# How to add spaces between font awesome icons and text in Latex "Awesome Resume/CV" template resume

Tags: templates, cv, awesome-cv

I am currently writing my resume in latex and decided to model it off of [this template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/awesome-resume-cv) I found [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/). I have gotten everything to work except that I can't figure out how to add space between the font awesome icons and the text next to them at the top of the page.

This is the part of the .cls file that seems to control whether or not the icons show up on the page (from what I can tell):

```
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %                Commands for elements of CV structure
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Define a header for CV
    % Usage: \makecvheader
    \newcommand*{\makecvheader}{
      \begin{center}
        \headerfirstnamestyle{
          \@firstname
        } \headerlastnamestyle{
          \@lastname
        }
        \\
        \vspace{0.4mm}
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@position}}{}{\headerpositionstyle{\@position\\}}
        \vspace{0.4mm}
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@address}}{}{\headeraddressstyle{\@address\\}}
        \vspace{-0.5mm}
        \headersocialstyle{
          \newbool{isstart}
          \setbool{isstart}{true}
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}
            {}
            {
              \faMobile\ \@mobile
              \setbool{isstart}{false}
            }
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}
            {}
            {
              \ifbool{isstart}
                {
                  \setbool{istart}{false} 
                }
                {\@headersocialsep}
              \href{mailto:\@email}{\faEnvelope\ \@email}
            }
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}
            {}
            {
              \ifbool{isstart}
                {
                  \setbool{istart}{false} 
                }
                {\@headersocialsep}
              \href{http://\@homepage}{\faHome\ \@homepage}
            }
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@github}}
            {}
            {
              \ifbool{isstart}
                {
                  \setbool{istart}{false} 
                }
                {\@headersocialsep}
              {\href{https://github.com/\@github}{\faGithubSquare\ \@github}
            }
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@stackoverflowid}}
            {}
            {
              \ifbool{isstart}
                {
                  \setbool{istart}{false} 
                }
                {\@headersocialsep}
              \href{https://stackoverflow.com/users/\@stackoverflowid}{\faStackOverflow\ \@stackoverflowname}
            }
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@linkedin}}
            {}
            {
              \ifbool{isstart}
                {
                  \setbool{istart}{false} 
                }
                {\@headersocialsep}
              \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/\@linkedin}{\faLinkedinSquare\ \@linkedin}
            }
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@twitter}}
            {}
            {
              \ifbool{isstart}
                {
                  \setbool{istart}{false} 
                }
                {\@headersocialsep}
              \href{https://twitter.com/\@twitter}{\faTwitter\ \@twitter}
            }
          \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}
            {}
            {
              \ifbool{isstart}
                {
                  \setbool{istart}{false} 
                }
                {\@headersocialsep}
              \faSkype\ \@skype
            }
        } \\
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}
          {}
          {\vspace{6.0mm}\headerquotestyle{\@quote\\}\vspace{5.0mm}}
      \end{center}
    }
```

And this is the part that controls the vertical bars used to separate the information:

```
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %                Commands for extra
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Define separator for social informations in header
    % Usage: \headersocialsep{<separator>}
    % Default: \quad\textbar\quad
    \newcommand*{\headersocialsep}[1][\quad\textbar\quad]{\def\@headersocialsep{#1}}
    \headersocialsep
```

Finally, this is the part that is responsible for creating commands for the personal information

```
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %                Commands for personal information
    %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Define writer's name
    % Usage: \name{<firstname>}{<lastname>}
    % Usage: \firstname{<firstname>}
    % Usage: \lastname{<lastname>}
    % Usage: \familyname{<familyname>}
    \newcommand*{\name}[2]{\def\@firstname{#1}\def\@lastname{#2}}
    \newcommand*{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
    \newcommand*{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
    \newcommand*{\familyname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
    \def\@familyname{\@lastname}

    % Define writer's address
    % Usage: \address{<address>}
    \newcommand*{\address}[1]{\def\@address{#1}}

    % Define writer's position
    % Usage: \name{<position>}
    \newcommand*{\position}[1]{\def\@position{#1}}

    % Defines writer's mobile (optional)
    % Usage: \mobile{<mobile number>}
    \newcommand*{\mobile}[1]{\def\@mobile{#1}}

    % Defines writer's email (optional)
    % Usage: \email{<email adress>}
    \newcommand*{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}

    % Defines writer's homepage (optional)
    % Usage: \homepage{<url>}
    \newcommand*{\homepage}[1]{\def\@homepage{#1}}

    % Defines writer's github (optional)
    % Usage: \github{<github-nick>}
    \newcommand*{\github}[1]{\def\@github{#1}}

    % Defines writer's linked-in (optional)
    % Usage: \linkedin{<linked-in-nick>}
    \newcommand*{\linkedin}[1]{\def\@linkedin{#1}}

    % Defines writer's stackoverflow profile (optional)
    % Usage: \stackoverflow{<so userid>}{<so username>}
    %   e.g.https://stackoverflow.com/users/123456/sam-smith
    %       would be \stackoverflow{123456}{sam-smith}
    \newcommand*{\stackoverflow}[2]{\def\@stackoverflowid{#1}\def\@stackoverflowname{#2}}

    % Defines writer's skype (optional)
    % Usage: \skype{<skype account>}
    \newcommand*{\skype}[1]{\def\@skype{#1}}

    % Defines writer's twitter (optional)
    % Usage: \twitter{<twitter handle>}
    \newcommand*{\twitter}[1]{\def\@twitter{#1}}
```

I've tried inserting `\hspace{}`'s where I think they should go, but to no avail. If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: That template is online for just 20 hours and already the first question gets in.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** The template has been updated. It is now possible to define the separator between the icon and the content for all instances at once. By default, it is a `\space`, but can be changed to a `\quad` or something to your liking.

`\renewcommand{\acvHeaderIconSep}{\quad}`

---

The folloing is now obsolete and won't work anymore. 
Add to preamble:

```
\patchcmd{\makecvheader}{\\ \vspace{0.4mm}}{\\[.4mm]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvheader}{\ }{\hspace{2em}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvheader}{\ }{\hspace{2em}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvheader}{\ }{\hspace{2em}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvheader}{\ }{\hspace{2em}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvheader}{\ }{\hspace{2em}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvheader}{\ }{\hspace{2em}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvheader}{\ }{\hspace{2em}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvheader}{\ }{\hspace{2em}}{}{}
```

Comment: Problem i have with templates: They define a set layout, and almost every user wants to change that predefined layout. *I will not buy this record, it is scratched*